# How to perform a single epoch of training with Huggingface's Trainer?

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I would like to define a Huggingface Trainer object, with a set of training parameters including a linear schedule for the learning rate annealing over a given set of epochs, and then proceed to train a single epoch at a time maintaining the state of the Trainer (optimizer/schedule/etc..) over the epochs.

What I would like to do would look something like:

```py
for i in range(epochs):
    data = modify_data()
    trainer.train_dataset = data["train"]
    trainer.train_one_epoch()
```

If I just set the `num_train_epochs` parameter to 1 in TrainingArguments, the learning rate scheduler will bring the learning rate to 0.0 between two epochs, making training useless after the first epoch.
If I just create a new Trainer at each iteration I lose the state of the learning rate schedule.

Does anyone know how to make a Trainer object train for a single epoch at a time?

PS: I'm using the pytorch backend

Edited to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Number of training epocs can be added in TrainingArguments, here is an example:

```
from transformers import TrainingArguments, Trainer
training_args = TrainingArguments("test-trainer", num_train_epochs=1)

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(checkpoint, num_labels=2)

trainer = Trainer(
    model,
    training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_datasets["validation"],
    data_collator=data_collator,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)
trainer.train()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this is not really what I was asking. I am in a situation where the trainer object is already completely defined and initalized. I would need to make it stop training after a single epoch, despite its training arguments containing `num_training_epochs=10`

Comment: That will not adhere to the Trainer’s design pattern! Hence, that cannot be done!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the training after one epoch, you can define a class which extends the TrainerCallback (See [code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/trainer_callback.py) or checkout [huggingface implementations](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/callback) as reference). Eg:

```
class StopCallback(TrainerCallback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, args, state, control, logs=None, **kwargs):
        control.should_training_stop = True
```

Afterwards, you can pass this StopCallback as args when u define Trainer. Eg:

```
trainer = Trainer(
model,
training_args,
train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["train"],
eval_dataset=tokenized_datasets["validation"],
data_collator=data_collator,
tokenizer=tokenizer,
compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
callbacks=[StopCallback()]
```

)